# How to use a different template for dynamic link when clicked in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-templates

All, i am facing an issue that i am hoping that someone can help me solve. I have a service that returns a list of Users with the corresponding link that when click it requires user to login and once login is successful, user is presented with the user info. How do i allow a user to click on this link and use a template to show their details. I want to re-use this partial template for all users

example:
Data: {{user.url}} yields: http://localhost:5555/user/randi333
Data: {{user.url}} yields: http://localhost:5555/user/rkds333

```
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td><a ng-href="{{user.url}}">User Details</a></td> 
            <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.gender | gender}}</td>
            <td>{{user.address}}</td>
            <td>{{user.city}}</td>
            <td>{{user.state}}</td>
            <td>{{user.ZipCode}}</td>
            <td>{{user.country}}</td>
            <td>{{user.enrollmentEntitysCount}}</td>
            <td>{{user.telephone}}</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
var consumewebservice = angular
                          .module("myconsumewebservice", ["ngRoute"])
                          .config(function ($routeProvider) {
                              $routeProvider
                                .when("/home", {

                                    templateUrl: "Templates/home.html",
                                    controller: "homeController"
                                })
                                .when("/user", {

                                    templateUrl: "Templates/user.html",
                                    controller: "webserviceController"
                                })
                              .when("/user/{{hash}}", {

                                  templateUrl: "Templates/userdetails.html",
                                  controller: "webserviceController"
                              })
                          })
                          .controller("webserviceController", function ($scope, $http,$log,$location,$anchorScroll) {

                              var successfulcallback = function (response) {
                                  $scope.users = response.data;
                                  $log.info(response);
                              };
                              var errorcallback = function (response) {
                                  $scope.error = response.data;
                                  $log.error(response);
                              };
                              $http.get('/api/users/')
                                  .then(successfulcallback, errorcallback);


                             $scope.scrollTo = function (firstname) {
                                  $location.hash(firstname);
                                  $anchorScroll();
                             }


                              //Scope to change view where we want the data to display
                              $scope.changeView = function (view) {
                                  $location.path(view); // path not hash
                              }
                                  $scope.search = function (item) {
                                      if ($scope.searchText == undefined) {
                                          return true;
                                      }
                                      else {
                                          if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toLowerCase()) != -1 || item.city.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                                              return true;
                                          }
                                      }
                                      return false;

                                  }
                                  $scope.sortColumn = "firstname";
                                  $scope.reverseSort = false;
                                  $scope.sortData = function (column) {
                                      $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn == column) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
                                      $scope.sortColumn = column;
                                  }
                                  $scope.getSortClass = function (column) {
                                      if ($scope.sortColumn == column) {
                                          return $scope.reverseSort ? 'arrow-down' : 'arrow-up';
                                      }
                                      return '';
                                  }
                              }
                              );
```

when i click on the link it takes me to the /user/{{username}}    these are different for different user name and i am getting   xml results back. i need to have this use a template that when the link is clicked for any user it will use that as the template and read and format those data....please assist

Comment: Not clear what specific problem is. Should be using `:routeParam` in url not `{{routeParam}}`

Comment: This was a great pointer that actually let me look at state params and Route params... solve my issue using Route params... i will add my solution below

Answer (score 0):

Use state reference here. Replace **ng-href with ui-sref with stateParams**.

```
<td>{{user.id}}</td>
<td><a ui-sref="userDetail({userDetail: user})">User Details</a></td> 
<td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
<td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
<td>{{user.gender | gender}}</td>
<td>{{user.address}}</td>
<td>{{user.city}}</td>
<td>{{user.state}}</td>
<td>{{user.ZipCode}}</td>
<td>{{user.country}}</td>
<td>{{user.enrollmentEntitysCount}}</td>
<td>{{user.telephone}}</td>
```

...and fetch the user object in the profile view of user.

Comment: thank you for this great pointer and i was able to solve the problem below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was able to solve my problem and i wanted to post the solution here.. Thank guys your pointers actually lead me to the solution:

My controller i pass in the route params:

```
.controller("userdetailsController", function ($scope, $http, $log, $location, $routeParams, ModalService) {
var successfulcallback = function (response, modal) {
    $scope.userdetail = response.data;
    $log.info(response);
    console.log("now on the userdetails controller success")

};
var errorcallback = function (response) {
    $scope.error = response.data;
    $log.error(response);
};
$http.get('/api/users/'+ $routeParams.id)
    .then(successfulcallback, errorcallback);
```

})

user controller
    .controller("userController", function ($scope, $http, $log, $location, ModalService) {

```
    var successfulcallback = function (response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
        $log.info(response);
    };
    var errorcallback = function (response) {
        $scope.error = response.data;
        $log.error(response);
    };



    $http.get('/api/users/')
        .then(successfulcallback, errorcallback);
```

Then in my configuration i added configuration with the parameter

```
   .when("/user/:id", {
                            templateUrl: "Templates/user-details.html",
                            controller: "userdetailsController"

                        })
```

In my html template i added the paramater

```
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">

        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td> <a href="#/user/{{user.username}}" >{{user.username}}</a></td>

        <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.gender | gender}}</td>
        <td>{{user.address}}</td>
        <td>{{user.city}}</td>
        <td>{{user.state}}</td>
        <td>{{user.ZipCode}}</td>
        <td>{{user.country}}</td>
        <td>{{user.enrollmentEntitysCount}}</td>
        <td>{{user.telephone}}</td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So when i navigate from user list and click on user id  i am routed to the template and controller with the passed id and are able to build the url for the service to grab the information for the specific user and then pass that data back....

Comment: another great resouce is here: found this after: http://www.kendar.org/?p=/tutorials/angularjs/part03